# Terminate custom avy repeated command

Tags: defun, avy

I am using a repeated command in doom-emacs on Mac OS which I borrowed from some other thread here:

```
(defun avy-delete-line-repeat (count &optional all-frames)
  "Wrapper around `other-window' to continue to jump to other with key o."
  (interactive "p")
  (avy-kill-whole-line count )
  (message "Use o to jump to next window.")
(avy-delete-line-repeat 1)
  (set-transient-map
   (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
     (define-key map (kbd "o")
       (lambda () (interactive) (avy-delete-line-repeat 1)))
     map)))
```

I would like to achieve an improvement of the repeated behaviour in a sense that I could terminate/break the loop with some modifier.
What I mean by that is that instead of selecting a line (here for deletion) with avy chars, which could be for example `h i` I could instead press `h M-i` so that the command terminates.

So it would be more general treating both the repetition, and at the same time having the possibility to break the loop without pressing extra `esc`.
One would achieve one `esc` click less which would turn out in a lot considering I am using this command quite often.